# Error: control may reach end of non-void function in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I want to return "K" when setLocationType is "ABC Office" and return "W" when setLocationType is "ABCDE Office". I am getting "control may reach end of non-void function" error and I am not able to proceed further.

```
+ (NSString*) retrieveLocationType
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *setLocationType = [prefs stringForKey:locationType];
    if (setLocationType == @"ABC Office"){
        return @"K";
    }
    else if (setLocationType == @"ABCDE Office"){
        return @"W";
    }
}
```

Comment: what if both if and else if fails? You need to have a return statemtn below all these conditions, so if everything fails, a default value should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

The error is given by the fact that the compiler finds a structure like the following

```
if (condition1) { return foo; }
else if (condition2) { return bar; }
```

And what happens when both `condition1` and `condition2` are false? No `return` statement is executed but the function must return a value of type `NSString`. You must change the statements into something like

```
if (condition1) { .. }
else if (condition2) { .. }
else { return baz; }
```

or

```
if (condition1) { .. }
else { .. }
```

Mind that comparing `NSString` with `==` operator compares just the memory address of the objects, you should use `isEqualToString:`.